# Vertical scroll add/remove class between two points

Tags: jquery

I have got a basic code working on my local machine

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 620) {

    $("#slidetwo").addClass("fixed");
} else {
     $("#slidetwo").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

However i want the class to be removed if scroll after a certain point how is this doable - I have added (scroll <= 1000)  in hope but failed

```
if (scroll >= 620) (scroll <= 1000) {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use and operator in if statement:

```
if (scroll >= 620 && scroll <= 1000) {
```

Complete Code.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll >= 620 && scroll <= 1000) 
  $("#slidetwo").addClass("fixed");
 else 
  $("#slidetwo").removeClass("fixed");
});
```